# using sed to remove equals sign from a file

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to remove the equals signs from this file and pipe it to a new file:

```
I am a file to be edited.
A unique file with my own words.
T=h=e=r=e a=r=e i=s=s=u=e=s w=i=t=h t=h=i=s l=i=n=e
```

I tried `cat FixMeWithSed.txt | sed 's/=//' > FileFixedWithSed.txt` but it only replaced the first equals sign.

```
I am a file to be edited.
A unique file with my own words.
Th=e=r=e a=r=e i=s=s=u=e=s w=i=t=h t=h=i=s l=i=n=e
```

I am not sure how to select all of the equals signs instead of only the first one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `g` flag to do a **g**lobal replacement. Otherwise, it just happens once.

```
cat FixMeWithSed.txt | sed 's/=//g' > FileFixedWithSed.txt
```

By the way, `sed` can read from a file so you don't need `cat` here:

```
sed 's/=//g' FixMeWithSed.txt > FileFixedWithSed.txt
```

Comment: Great thanks!  I was hoping this would be a simple fix.

Comment: +1 for removing the unnecessary use of `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sed -i "s/=//g" file.in
```

to replace = on the same file, without creating a new one.
Otherwise you can even use

```
tr -d '=' < file.in > file.out
```